# How to get an object to track a surface using Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to keep on object tracking a surface in my Three.js application

I have a large 3D surface/track/maze in which my object is allowed to move

Arrow keys control heading/rotate and accelerate/decelerate

Now I need to figure out how to keep the object on the surface - 
Object should be able to 'drive' NSEW & Front/Back

Any hints gratefully accepted

Answer (score 0):

I use the lib to manage the movements http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/FirstPersonControls.js.html

and to keep it on the floor, I used cannon.js [http://cannonjs.org/] for physics.

Comment: I have been looking through the cannon.js examples and can't see the tie up between my Three.js objects and the cannon world   My Three.js scene contains my 3D surface/track/maze is a model loaded in from Blender --- it is a

Comment: I have been looking through the cannon.js examples and can't see the tie up between my Three.js objects and the cannon world  How does the Cannon code know what shape my Three.js 3D surface/track/maze is - so that it can constrain my 'Character' object to its surface  many thanks for your input